# SMTPAddressFailedException: 530 SMTP authentication is required while sending mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

i had problem while sending mails useing java this is my code

```
package callcentersystem;

public class Email {

    private String topic = "my test";
    private String myMassage = "nothinge";

    public void untitledMethod(String to) {
        String host = "my ip adresse";
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(utils.Constants.From));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(topic);
            message.setText(myMassage);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            System.out.println("the massage didnt send");
            throw new RuntimeException(mex);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my crash massage

```
the massage didnt send
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:        javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 530 SMTP authentication is required.

at callcentersystem.Email.untitledMethod(Email.java:33)
at callcentersystem.CallCenterSystem.main(CallCenterSystem.java:10)
Caused by: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 530 SMTP authentication is    required.

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1446)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:736)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
at callcentersystem.Email.untitledMethod(Email.java:29)
... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 530 SMTP authentication is required.

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1344)
... 5 more
```

i tried all ways to solve this problem but it dosent work and i setup a hmailserver administrator and i use it that solved my localhost problem

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there is a need for authentication credentials for this SMTP server, as it is clear from the nested exception: `530 SMTP authentication is required`

You need to set Authenticator instance for the session:

```
...
Authenticatior authenticator =
         new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication(
                  "youruser@yourhost.com", "yourpassword");
            }
         };
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, authenticator);
...
```

Change *youruser@yourhost.com* and *yourpassword* to actual credentials on the email server where you are trying to send the message. You need a valid account on this server because it requires authentication.

As a side note that is not related to the question, are you sure you want to use [Session.getDefaultInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getDefaultInstance(java.util.Properties,%20javax.mail.Authenticator)) and not [Session.getInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getInstance(java.util.Properties,%20javax.mail.Authenticator))? Read documentation about implications.

Comment: But did you change credentials to the actual credentials on the email server were you are trying to send?

Comment: i tried anthor code but this time my error is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect

Comment: Are there any other details in the error? AuthenticationFailedException to me seems pretty obvious, most chances you set invalid user name and password. Do these credentials work in email client, say, Thunderbird?

Comment: May it be you ask a wrong question? The errors you get are because you are not able to _authenticate_ on the server. Do you actually ask how to authenticate on SMTP server, or do you ask how to disable authentication on your hmailserver so you don't need to supply credentials? If the question is the second one, the code is completely irrelevant and you need just to disable authentication on the hmailserver.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by this code

```
public void untitledMethod(ArrayList to, String password, String message) {
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", utils.Constants.From);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(utils.Constants.From, password);
        }
    });
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(utils.Constants.From));
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < to.size(); i++) {
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress((String) to.get(i));
        }

        for (InternetAddress toAddres : toAddress) {
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddres);
            mimeMessage.setSubject("Clinic Support");
            mimeMessage.setText(message);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, 587, utils.Constants.From, password);
            transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        }

    } catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but you must make sure with your email and password that you use it to send mails